# Could not cast value of type - initialising with protocol (Swift)

Tags: swift

I'm implementing simple MVP pattern for View Controller in Swift (3).

View is defined like a protocol:

```
protocol WirelessSpeakersView {

    func present()
    func goBack()
    func alertSaveFailed()
}
```

And I'm constructing the presenter in the ViewController like this:

```
class WirelessSpeakersViewController: UIViewController, WirelessSpeakersView  {

    private let presenter: WirelessSpeakersPresenter = WirelessSpeakersPresenter(view: self as! WirelessSpeakersView)
```

But the last line produces run time exception

> Could not cast value of type '(WirelessSpeakersViewController)
>   -> () -> WirelessSpeakersViewController' (0x102cfbf20) to 'WirelessSpeakersView' (0x102cfbf58).

which I do not get. Why the type naming looks so complex (-> () -> ) ? 
I do not expect any difficulties cause the ViewController properly implements View protocol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make variable presenter lazy or initialize it after viewcontroller initialization. This error might be because its trying to type cast viewcontroller object before getting initalized.

```
private lazy var presenter: WirelessSpeakersPresenter = {
        let p = WirelessSpeakersPresenter(view: self as! WirelessSpeakersView)
        return p
    }()
```